# Do i need to uninstall xampp to use acquia for drupal8?

Tags: php, drupal, xampp, acquia

I am using xampp for some php projects. Now I want to learn drupal8 and want to install acquia for that. Can it conflict with xampp?

Answer (score 1):

I assume when you say 'acquia' you mean Acquia Dev Desktop 2.

And for that the answer is: no; there should be no conflict having those in paralel if you used default settings(ports and such). However I personally experienced some issues with mysql when placed on same partition with win7.